# Order of magnitudes comparisons

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I need your help with the following.

I need to determine how to order (functions) the following :

\begin{align}
&f(x)=(x/2)^{(x/2)} \\
&g(x)=x!
\end{align}

Note:
I got both of them are equal ( $f(x)= \theta(x \log x)$ and $g(x)= \theta(x \log x)$ )
But I do not know how it really true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Try taking logs of both functions.  Note that when you take logs of $g(x)$ you end up with a sum that you should find easy to bound.